# How to format text in input box with css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the font color of the placeholder text that appears in the input boxes before the visitor types any text.

Here's my example http://santa.parseapp.com/

See the text boxes at the bottom of the page. I think it's using a user agent stylesheet at the moment, which means the form elements dont have styles created?

I'm not sure which element I need to target with CSS. Here's what I've go:

```
form input[type=text] {
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  background-color: #FF2950;
  color: #fff;
  }
```

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: I've added the code where the input box is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking to style the placeholder text, yeah?

Generally speaking, placeholder text gets the same styling as the element itself, apart from the colour. So in your example, the placeholder text will be `color: grey` and `font-size: 20px`.

If you want to target the placeholder text specifically, you need to use the :placeholder psuedo-class:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: blue;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
   color: blue;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: blue;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the constructive help.

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7r2d9/1/

```
form input[type=text]:focus {
  color: black;
}
```